# What kind of javascript code should stay in the html file?

Tags: javascript, html

How right is it put all the javascript code in the  tags of the html file?

Is it considered any better to put all the js code in separate .js files?

I've noticed that many sites (including this) have some js code written in html file itself(enclosed in script tags).

And lets say I decided to put all possible javascript code in separate files. Now, will those external files have access to the elements of the elements of the html document.

I mean, lets say I want to create a new `<p>` element with text everytime a user clicks a button. Will the external javascript file have access to the document elements to allow this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you reference the `.js` file in your HTML, the JavaScript will have access to all the elements on the page. This applies to dynamically created elements as well.

It is good practice to have as much JavaScript in external files as possible. There shouldn't be a reason for having JavaScript code in the page itself.

Comment: The main reason for having JS in the page in my experience is server side code that adds scripts to the page during rendering for functionality it needs. I would agree that you shouldn't in general hand code JS into a page though.

Answer (score 2):

Any JS code in any referenced JS files will have access to your html.

Javascript is generally meant to be separated out into a separate file(s) but for whatever reason, some people go against that, and it isn't really the end of the world.

Answer (score 2):

Separate `.js` files will result in multiple `http` requests, it will make your page loading little slower,however both have their own pros and cons link for example having `.js` files will result in caching thus making your page load faster when user revisits your page, as well as you do not need to change it on each and every page you are using, just by editing a single file, on the other hand its cons are if the files are cached and if you change sometimes the changes are not affected as browser has a cached `.js` so some people do rename their javascripts like **abcv1.js, abcv2.js** etc, using inline scripts reduces your http requests,it also doesn't get cached by the browser so whenever you change it will be affected on your web page to all the visitors at that right moment, because there's no question of the script getting cached..

If you want external `.js` files you can bind all scripts in a single file to reduce your `http` requests

Answer (score 1):

everyone's correct above. One thing to bear in mind is that .js files are cached by the browser where as inline code is not. This has numerous advantages in that the browser does not have to request the javascript every time a user visits your page, so less data is sent down the connection and the page will load quicker the second time. Also lowers your bandwidth usage.

You can make this faster too by [minifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_%28programming%29)  your js file

Answer (score 0):

having javascript in external .js files is 'the done thing' to keep code tidy, once you reference the external file in your html, it effectively becomes identical to javascript that is included in the html

Answer (score 0):

Javascript held in external `.js` files will act in exactly the same way as if the javascript was directly within the HTML.

The advantage to having it in `.js` files is that those files are generally cached by the browser, and therefore do not need to be download each and every time the page is loaded. The disadvantage to this is if you need to make a change to the file for any reason, you will need to rename the file to guarantee that the latest changes are picked up.

The only time I normally include javacsript as part of the page is if I need specific values to be used which is passed from the "code behind" as part of my ASP.NET projects.
For example `var myJSVar = <%=_myCSVar%>;`

Answer (score 0):

i always try to keep it down to variables that needs to get written at render time and are more or less unique. like localisation (even thou im starting to use a service for that aswell) the rest can (and shod) be saved in external files and cached by the browser